# AbstractMethodError from slf4j in Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, slf4j

I have a Spring application with Hibernate as persistency layer. For logging I'am using slf4j with log4j as binding.

My pom.xml looks like this.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--DEPENDENCYS FOR HIBERNATE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--DEPENDENCY FOR BEANVALIDATION-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--DRIVER FOR MYSQL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--REQUIRED FOR FILEUPLOAD-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--LIB FOR JSON CONVERTING-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Solr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--Logging-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

So, when I deploy this application on a tomcat7 on Ubuntu with Java 1.8 everything works fine (My laptop). But when I'm trying to deploy it on the production system (Win 8, Java 7, Tomcat7 and Tomcat8 tried) I get the following error:

```
21-Oct-2014 17:57:50.016 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
21-Oct-2014 17:57:50.079 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21-Oct-2014 17:57:50.079 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The standard error says "startup failed due to previous errors"...

Any Ideas what could be the reason?

---

**EDIT**
The dependency tree from 'mvn dependency:tree' looks like this:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.18:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-extras:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet-wildcard:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-freemarker:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-velocity:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-el:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-mvel:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-ognl:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jboss:javassist:jar:3.7.ga:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-compat:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-solr:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-kuromoji:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-phonetic:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.0.5-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6:system
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.0.5-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.0.5-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.0a:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.0.5-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.7:runtime
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

---

**EDIT 2**
so... Now I tried to exclude the `commons-logging` things from my projects pom.xml. But it was also not very effective. The error message stays exactly the same... But I recognised something very interesting...

When I open the output war (I generate it with `mvn clean install`) with an archive manager and navigate to the WEB-INF/lib folder i can see all the jar-files, which were in my pom.xml during the past. So, there are the jars of 3 different versions of slf4j, multiple log4j versions and many other libs, which could be in conflict.
The strange thing is, that all these jar-files does not appear in the `mvn dependency:tree`.

Any idea, how I can get rid of those files?

Comment: For starters there is a difference in JDK I would start by fixing that. Next check your dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree` and make sure that you don't have conflicting SLF4J jars (or other jars.

Comment: @M.Deinum Unfortunately the solution of my problem is not that easy to find... Changing the JDK changes nothing and 'mvn dependency:tree' only shows _slf4j.jars_ from the _slf4j-log4j12_ dependency. Is it possible, another dependency creates a conflict?

Comment: Post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`. Also make sure that you don't have any additional dependencies in for the tomcat/lib directory on your local system.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I've postet the dependency tree now in the post above. In the tomcat/lib directory are only the default jars, which are included when tomcat is installed, could they be a problem?

Comment: One thing is that you also use commons-logging you are mixing 2 different logging strategies. I would exclude `commons-logging` and add `jcl-over-slf4j` as a dependency instead. Could be just a stupid library loading issue (maybe the order of loading is different on Ubuntu then on Windows for instance).

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried no to exclude the `commons-logging` stuff. But it changed nothing (see Edit 2)

Comment: Problem solved. Just deleted the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and created the war with `mvn clean install` again. I don't know where the lib folder came from. Maybe from IntelliJ IDEA or from another tool... Thanks for the answers!